Editing questions: who, what, why etc
Before I go into the details, I want to mention that recently there has been some venting in comments and some people retaliating to others' editing which is not acceptable.
For any discussion on the actions of another user these should be done in chat and in a respectable way. If necessary a moderator can be invited to join in the conversation. Comments should never be used for discussions.
No user should use the system to retaliate against another users actions. If there is an issue with another user, contact a moderator and discuss the issue with them.

Who can edit? Editing is a privilege of everyone on the site. Not just moderators.
Why should I edit? Editing is done to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning. Editing improves the overall quality of the site and you also earn reputation for approved edits.
How does it work? Once an edit has been received it goes into a queue for high reputation users and moderators to approve or reject
What are some reasons my edit will be rejected? The main reason is if your edit does not provide any improvement e.g If it is only adding a single comma or it slightly improves one sentence but makes another sentence slightly worse etc.
What happens if too many of my edits are rejected? If you provide too many low quality edits you will not be allowed to suggest further edits for a period of time.

Refer to the post "What is the etiquette for modifying posts?" for general guidelines on etiquette for modifying posts.

If you are not happy with a way a post has been edited you have the option of rolling back a post to its original state. If both parties are still not happy with the state of the post then this should be taken to chat for a friendly discussion to reach a consensus.
Any unresolved issues should be taken up with a moderator and anything that needs to go further (rage, threats, spam etc.) can be done through the contact us link in the site footer on the bottom of every page.

If you look a bit more carefully, you will observe that all recent edit suggestions followed the etiquette for modifying posts guidelines carefully. I fixed grammar and spelling, clarified meaning, and replaced non-descriptive titles while respecting the author's style. Is that what "retaliation" looks like?

@Village - If you have a particular example you would like to discuss further please take it to the chatroom as indicated above. Comments are not the place for discussions.

@Village Actually, in some places you didn't clarify meaning, you changed it, and there I re-edited, but in other places I liked your changes so I kept them.

Editing should not be considered something secondary on this site, since it's not even considered as such by the FAQ and so by the ones who created it and manage it. Stack Exchange sites are meant to be a great resource for other people who, when researching on internet, find info on here. That's why we also have the rules for what questions can be asked and what not.
Editing makes it possible for others to make answers and questions look better to visitors, and the ones who edit do it, or try to do it, by certain standards.
I have obviously, like others, personal taste in some things. But for those things, if not appreciated, there is a Rollback function. In any case, not all changes are made according to personal taste. The edits made according to the language-related rules are not to be considered as such.
If I see someone not capitalizing, someone not using spaces appropriately or "Writing Like This", then correcting them is not my personal taste anymore. At this point, someone could say that such things are "those user's style/personal taste".
The answer is: yes, they are, but remember that this is not a blog or a personal site.
On my blog/personal site, I can do whatever I want, but this is meant to be a public reference site, so some standards must be met, otherwise it's  a mess. The question titles, aren't exactly titles and that's why almost no-one writes "Why Is It That..." because I know that in English titles can be capitalized like that.
Sorry for the long post, and although I have more to say, I think it's enough for now eheh...
By the way, check this post by Jeff: The Great Edit Wars.
